# Delete existing files from Kudu /site/wwwroot/ before new Azure app deployment

Tags: azure, curl, kudu, azure-appservice

I'm trying to delete my previous app deployment files present in kudu /site/wwwroot/ before a new Azure deployment. I tried running the curl command with delete method -

curl -u username:password -X DELETE "https://{web-app-name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/"

But I got the following error :-
*Cannot delete directory. It is either not empty or access is not allowed*

Any idea how I can delete the files via the terminal window without actually having to manually delete them?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Visual Studio for deployment you can check this box before deployment,

[image]

Or you can use Powershell script by calling [**`Kudu VFS API`**](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#vfs)

> DELETE
> https://{site}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/wwwroot/some.config.default

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan! I'm not using Visual Studio. I'm actually using jenkins for deployment process. And I need to clean up the App service before new deployment. 
Is there any way to delete the files with a shell/bash command?

Comment: call the api above

Comment: Yes I tried, but I got the error - Cannot delete directory. It is either not empty or access is not allowed